# Working when select but doesn't work when written in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I use these command but it only work when i select normally

```
SELECT INSTITUTE as INSTITUTE,
custno+ REPLICATE(' ', 16 - len(custno)) AS CUSTNO,
REPLICATE(' ', 32 - len(LASTNAME))+LASTNAME as LASTNAME
from TB_CUSTOMERS_DAILY
```

but when be used in stored procedure with bcp utility,it doesn't work

```
USE [test]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE        [dbo].[DO_TRANSACTION_AML]

AS
Declare   @V_SQL_TMP     VARCHAR (4000)
EXEC DO_LOG @MSG_IN = 'START DO_TRANSACTION_AML'

SET @V_SQL_TMP = 'bcp "select CUST_INSTITUTE,CUST_CUSTNO + REPLICATE (' ', 
16 - len(CUST_CUSTNO)) from test.dbo.TB_TRANSACTIONS_AML" queryout 
"C:\Users\nvhun\test\Transaction_AML.txt" -c -UTF8 -T -Slocalhost'  
EXEC xp_cmdshell @V_SQL_TMP
```

Comment: doesn't work ? Does it give a wrong result or an error ? What is the question ?

Comment: with BCP utility? Where do you see any bulk load here? WHY do you use bcp? Did you mean sqlcmd?

Comment: @t-clausen.dk my expected output is printing out to a text file

Comment: see my comment below @sepupic

Comment: Your "comment" should be the part of your question, just make an edit of your question and copy your code there

Comment: @sepupic i've added to my question. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should double the quotes in your string variable:

```
SET @V_SQL_TMP = 'bcp "select CUST_INSTITUTE,CUST_CUSTNO + REPLICATE ('' '', 
16 - len(CUST_CUSTNO)) from test.dbo.TB_TRANSACTIONS_AML" queryout 
"C:\Users\nvhun\test\Transaction_AML.txt" -c -UTF8 -T -Slocalhost'
```

(see near REPLICATE)

Comment: It still do not print out to text file. When i just use  SET @V_SQL_TMP = 'bcp "select * from test.dbo.TB_TRANSACTIONS_AML" queryout 
"C:\Users\nvhun\test\Transaction_AML.txt" -c -UTF8 -T -Slocalhost'. It print to text file with all value in table test.dbo.TB_TRANSACTIONS_AML.

Comment: Your code is different. In the first case you select from TB_CUSTOMERS_DAILY and in the second case from test.dbo.TB_TRANSACTIONS_AML. Did you try to execute your query from SSMS using test.dbo.TB_TRANSACTIONS_AML?

Comment: oh. i found problem here, without line break, it will work. thanks